# Backup to track fraud on Dedicated Server running Apache and MySQL

Tags: security, backup, dedicated-server

**Background**:

i am running a Dedicated Server with WHM/cPanel and i would like to know what to backup. My old VPS was hacked into using a [security vulnerability in TimThumb](http://blog.vaultpress.com/2011/08/02/vulnerability-found-in-timthumb/) and i was unable to track back who had done it because the logs were being deleted once in a while and some time had passed before i could analyze it, the logs were gone.

On my new (and hopefully secure:) server i would like to regularly backup logs and everything i should need to track down someone who executed malicious commands and web request on my server.

**Question**:

- What do i need to backup to track stuff like http events, SSH connections & etc?
- Where exactly are those files located?
- Is there an automated way of copying the files or doing this backup?

Please advise me on this task.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the httpd service Apache, you can backup the log files, typically found in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache`.

For SSH logins you can check the log files: `/var/log/auth(.log)`, `/var/log/secure(.log)` and you can dump the command `last` to a "log" file for backing  up as well by doing `last > /var/log/ssh_logins`.

You can automate backing up these files via cron and a custom backup script, or using something like `rsync` or [dervish](http://www.dirvish.org/)

Comment: Or better yet, use syslog-ng or rsyslog to push them immediately to a different server.  You can also change how long logs are kept for, how often they are rotated and when and whether they are compressed by editing the files in `/etc/logroatate.d/`.